# Symbols in shared libraries

Tags: c++, c, gcc, shared-libraries

I have done [this tutorial here](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/shared-libraries-linux-gcc.html) to learn how to generate shared libraries. I added some smaller things because I wanted to test something out. Here are ma source codes:

**strong text**

```
#ifndef foo_h__
#define foo_h__

void foo(void);

class CFoo
{
public:
    void fooing1();
    void fooing2(int a);
    void fooing3(int a, int b = 0);
};

#endif      // foo_h__
```

**foo.cpp**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "foo.h"

void foo(void)
{
    puts("Hello, I'm a shared library");
}

void CFoo::fooing1()
{
    puts("CFoo::fooing1()");
}

void CFoo::fooing2(int a)
{
    printf("CFoo::fooing2(%d)\n", a);
}

void CFoo::fooing3(int a, int b)
{
    printf("CFoo::fooing3(%d, %d)\n", a, b);
}
```

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "foo.h"

int main(void)
{
    puts("This is a shared library test...");
    foo();

    CFoo *foo1 = new CFoo();
    foo1->fooing1();
    foo1->fooing2(12);
    foo1->fooing3(1);
    foo1->fooing3(1, 2);
    delete foo1;


    return 0;
}
```

**And the build script**

```
g++ -c -Wall -Werror -fpic foo.cpp
g++ -shared -o libfoo.so foo.o
g++ -Wall -o test main.c -lfoo -L.
```

When typing the command `nm -D libfoo.so | c++filt`, I get this output:

```
 0000000000201040 B __bss_start
                  w __cxa_finalize
 0000000000201040 D _edata
 0000000000201048 B _end
 0000000000000818 T _fini
                  w __gmon_start__
 0000000000000640 T _init
                  w _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
                  w _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
                  w _Jv_RegisterClasses
                  U printf
                  U puts
 0000000000000796 T foo()
 00000000000007a8 T CFoo::fooing1()
 00000000000007c2 T CFoo::fooing2(int)
 00000000000007ea T CFoo::fooing3(int, int)
```

I have two questions:

1) Why do `printf` and `puts` have an `U` before their function names? And the functions `foo()`, `CFoo::fooing1()`, `CFoo::fooing2(int)` and `CFoo::fooing3(int, int)` does have a `T` before their function names?

2) What to do to get a `U` before the `CFoo` functions?

Comment: You should have read [nm command](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_nm.htm) manual page.

Comment: You can use `-C|--demangle` `nm` option instead of piping through `c++filt`.

Answer (score 3):

The [letter U means](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/nm.html) that the symbols `printf` and `puts` are undefined in the library code you have produced.  This is normal, as they are defined in another shared library.

The letter T means that the code is defined in the library file (the text section corresponds in fact to code; it shall not be confused with the data section).

If CFoo functions are meant to be the core content of your shared library, you'd better avoid makeing them U in your library. If you nevertheless want to achieve this :

- keep this `CFoo` function declared in the class header
- remove completely its in `foo.cpp`:  the code will compile but the function is missing (i.e. it's not defined at all in the library file)
- but call this function from another `CFoo` function in the `foo.cpp`:  the code will compile, and this time the library file will have this function defined as U:  a symbol whic is regularly declared , is needed, but was not found yet.

Comment: I need to make the `CFoo` functions to `U`, because I want to generate a small example of a problem I have.